# No application to open url about:blank error in Excel desktop add-in

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I have written an add-in for Microsoft Excel. The add-in works great on the web-based Excel, but I get the error below when I try to run it in the desktop version

[image]

This happens when the plugin tries to authenticate the user using a popup window. Anyone encountered this issue ?

Thanks
Matteo

Comment: Do you sideload your add-in on Mac? could you try it on windows and see if you observe the issue?